# How to change name of layers in tree

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext

I'm trying to change the name of the layers in the tree.
This is part of my code:

```
var layer_group1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layer_group1", 
                    url,
                    {
                        LAYERS: ['namespace:layer_a','namespace:layer_b','namespace:layer_c'],
                        format: "image/png",
                        transparent: "true",
                        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
                    },
                    {    

                        buffer: 0, 
                        displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                        isBaseLayer: false,
                        displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
                        yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}

                    } 
                );

var layer_group2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layer_group2", 
                    url,
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'namespace:layer_d',
                        format: "image/png",
                        transparent: "true",
                        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
                    },
                    {    
                        opacity:0.5,
                        buffer: 3,
                        displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                        displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
                        yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}

                    } 
                );


    mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
        border: true,
        region: "center",
        // we do not want all overlays, to try the OverlayLayerContainer
        map: mapa,
        center:[-6613943,-3793944],
        zoom: 7,
        layers: [ capaBase, layer_group1, layer_group2, gmap,gsat,vector]
    }    
)
```

I get the tree:

```
layer_group1
   |_ namespace:layer_a
   |_ namespace:layer_b
   |_ namespace:layer_c

layer_group2
   |_namespace:layer_d
```

But I want to expect:

```
layer_group1
   |_ Layer a
   |_ Layer b
   |_ Layer c

layer_group2
   |_ Layer d
```

How can I change the name of the layer in the tree?

PS: don't hesitate if you need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem and I don't have a complete answer, but for now I'm avoiding the use of the namespace in the layer call.

If you specify the workspace in the url like:

```
url =  http://host:port/geoserver/namespace/wms
```

Then you don't need to specify namespace when you call the layers:

```
var layer_group1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layer_group1", 
                url,
                {
                 // Here you change from "namespace:layer_a" to "layer_a"
                    LAYERS: ['layer_a','layer_b','layer_c'], 
                    format: "image/png",
                    transparent: "true",
                    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
                },
                {    

                    buffer: 0, 
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
                    yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}

                } 
            );
```

You'll get:

```
layer_group1
|_ layer_a
|_ layer_b
|_ layer_c
```

I know is not what you want, but it could help you.

**--------- UPDATE (03/07/2013) ---------------------**

I find a solution using a non-oficial script. Is not difficult to use, but you need to use specific GeoExt and Ext library versions (using the latest one didn't work for me; I'm using version 3.2.1 for ext-all and ext-base). Also, you need to add base layer or you'll receive notifications that you don't have a map projection (even if you declare one). Maybe there's some configuration to fix that, but the easiest thing for me was to add a base layer.

You can have a better answer [here](http://www.geoext.org/pipermail/users/2012-December/003159.html) and the [example](http://dev.geoext.org/geoext/sandbox/mapgears/geoext.ux/ux/LayerTreeBuilder/examples/tree-builder.html) (pointed in the previous URL).

Still not the optimal solution, but it works as expected so far. I'm going to vacations right now, so I don't have the time to post a minimal example but I could do it at my return if you want. Anyway, the example I posted below is a very good one.

Cheers!

Comment: I will try later. I didn't found the solution so this is progress! Please let me know if you find the solution :)

Comment: This is very embarrassing. I tried change the name of layer in GeoServer from `layer_a` to `Layer a` and it works! I can create layers with spaces in the name.

Comment: Any idea how I can use this with GeoExt 2 ?